# SharePoint Online takes hour to install the sharepoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am trying to write SharePoint hosted app and connecting to microsoft online Sharepoint portal (dev site). It takes more than hour to install the app on the sharepoint after i press f5 in visual studio. Similarly while uninstalling the sharepoint, again it is stuck and takes a long time to uninstall the app and sometime it does not uninstall the app. This happens only for SharePoint hosted app. Can any one please suggest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just had this problem on our server, on-premise and Office 365.

**If this is an on-premise server:**

If you are the administrator, go into the Timer Jobs, and look at the "App installation service" timer job.

The default is supposed to be every 5 minutes.

We found that ours was set at once a day at 12:00 am, which made it very unpleasant to install and retract applications.

**If this is a Office 365 server:**

The development team just made a patch on Friday July 26th. The problem should be fixed, but if it is not, just open a support ticket and let them know about the "App installation service" timer job not working correctly.

Here is the list of all timer jobs and their default values: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678870.aspx